# Does the Assassin rogue’s Death Strike feature double the damage from a poison that requires a saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue, poison, assassin

Let’s say you coat your weapon with [poison](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/running-the-game#Poisons) transmitted by injury from the DMG. As we know, the damage from these poisons are not tied to the attack roll but to a Con save, so the damage dice are not doubled on a crit. But how does it work with Death Strike? Should I double the damage rolled anyway?

The [Assassin rogue](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#Assassin)'s [Death Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#DeathStrike-363) feature states (PHB, p. 97):

> [...] When you attack and hit a creature that is surprised, it must make a Constitution saving throw (DC 8 + your Dexterity modifier + your proficiency bonus). On a failed save, double the damage of your attack against the creature.

Comment: Related: [Maximizing Assassin damage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126218/maximizing-assassin-damage)

Comment: Related: [Is Ice Knife's explosion damage affected by rolling a critical?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/91895/is-ice-knifes-explosion-damage-affected-by-rolling-a-critical) & [How much damage does a target take from the Assassin rogue's Death Strike on a failed save?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65264/how-much-damage-does-a-target-take-from-the-assassin-rogues-death-strike-on-a-f)

Comment: I think this is related: "[If an attack causes additional damage after a saving throw, is it counted as a separate source of damage for the purpose of failed death saves?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/152419)"

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 16):

## No, the poison's damage is not part of the attack and therefore not doubled

Death strike explictly states that the attack is doubled (emphasis mine):

> . . . On a failed save, double the damage of your **attack** against the creature. (PHB, p. 97)

Damage from poison applied to a weapon has been [clarified](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/536683487517224961) as being separate damage from the attack entirely, due to needing a saving throw, as you have referenced in your question. We can phrase this in this manner due to the ruling that poison damage is not doubled on a critical hit, and the definition of critical hit damage (emphasis mine):

> When you score a critical hit, you get to roll extra dice for the attack’s damage against the target. **Roll all of the attack’s damage dice twice** and add them together. Then add any relevant modifiers as normal. To speed up play, you can roll all the damage dice at once.
>
> For example, if you score a critical hit with a dagger, roll 2d4 for the damage, rather than 1d4, and then add your relevant ability modifier. **If the attack involves other damage dice, such as from the rogue’s Sneak Attack feature, you roll those dice twice as well.** (PHB, p. 196)

A couple clarifications here from the bolded text.

- The "attack's damage dice" are rolled twice. This means dice that are explicitly tied to the attack roll being a success.
- Sneak Attack is all-or-nothing and therefore part of the attack. If the attack misses, Sneak Attack does not occur. This is the same reason that Divine Smite damage is doubled on a critical hit.
- Poison damage is **not** tied to the attack, as the poison damage is not wholly dependent on the attack landing. The success of the poison is instead tied to a saving throw. The attack only matters in that it is the vehicle for delivering the poison; the rest of the poison damage mechanic is self-contained in the poison itself and not the attack.